# While loop doesnt work on the first time when accessing it for the second time

Tags: c, while-loop

Okay so I have run a function 4 times. It runs perfectly the first time but when i have to run that function again the 3 other time, i get the "*** INVALID ENTRY *** : " printf that i made when the user doesnt input a 'y' or 'Y' or 'n' or 'N'
Also, I am trying to make it so that whenever a user enters "Yes or No" it will prompt the "error message" but currently the way i wrote my program it takes only the first Character from the user" Ex: Inputs "Yes" the program will take only "Y" which makes the program think the user entered 'Y' which skips the error stage.

This is what is in my main

```
printf("Please enter 'Y' > ");
printf("    Result: %d\n", yes() );
printf("Please enter 'y' > ");
printf("    Result: %d\n", yes());
printf("Please enter 'N' > ");
printf("    Result: %d\n", yes());
printf("Please enter 'yes', then 'no', then 'n' > ");
printf("    Result: %d\n", yes());
```

And this is my part im trying to access.

```
int yes(void) {
    char singleLetter;
    int theResults = 0;
    scanf("%c", &singleLetter);
    while ((singleLetter != 'y') && (singleLetter != 'Y') && (singleLetter != 'n') && (singleLetter != 'N')) {


                clearKeyboard();
                printf("*** INVALID ENTRY *** <Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable>: ");
                scanf("%c", &singleLetter);

        } 

        if ((singleLetter == 'y') || (singleLetter == 'Y')) {
            theResults = theResults++;
        }
        if ((singleLetter == 'n') || (singleLetter == 'N')) {
            theResults = 0;
        }
        //printf("%c",singleLetter);
    return theResults;
}
```

The results are:

```
Please enter 'Y' > Y
    Result: 1
Please enter 'y' > y
*** INVALID ENTRY *** <Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable>: y
    Result: 1
Please enter 'N' > N
*** INVALID ENTRY *** <Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable>: N
    Result: 0
Please enter 'yes', then 'no', then 'n' > yes
*** INVALID ENTRY *** <Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable>: no
    Result: 0
```

EDIT::
I fixed the above code so it works fine
However when I call yes() from a different function i get this error:
This is the code im trying to call from:

```
void getName(struct Name *contactName) {

    printf("Please enter the contact's first name: ");
    scanf("%s", (*contactName).firstName);
    printf("Do you want to enter a middle intial(s)? (y or n): ");
    yes();

    if (yes() == 1) {
        printf("Please enter the contact's middle intial(s): ");
        scanf("%s", (*contactName).middleInitial);

    }

    printf("Please enter the contact's last name: ");
    scanf("%s", (*contactName).lastName);
}
```

I fixed the yes() code with

```
int yes(void) {
    char singleLetter;
    int theResults = 0;
    scanf("%c", &singleLetter);
    clearKeyboard();

    while ((singleLetter != 'y') && (singleLetter != 'Y') && (singleLetter != 'n') && (singleLetter != 'N')) {

                printf("*** INVALID ENTRY *** <Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable>: ");
                scanf("%c", &singleLetter);
                clearKeyboard();

        } 

        if ((singleLetter == 'y') || (singleLetter == 'Y')) {
            theResults = theResults + 1;
        }
        if ((singleLetter == 'n') || (singleLetter == 'N')) {
            theResults = 0;
        }

    return theResults;
}
```

i get this error. Literally makes me enter y 3 times, and i get a invalid entry code for no reason.

```
Do you want to enter a middle intial(s)? (y or n): y
*** INVALID ENTRY *** <Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable>: y
y
Please enter the contact's middle intial(s):
```

**EDIT PART 2**
I fixed my function yes() by doing this:

```
int yes(void) {
        char singleLetter = ' ';  
        int finalValue = -1; 
        int theResult = 0; 

        scanf(" %c", &singleLetter);
        clearKeyboard();

        do
        {
            switch (singleLetter)
            {

            case 'Y':
            case 'y':
                finalValue = 1;
                theResult = 1;
                break;

            case 'N':
            case 'n':
                finalValue = 0;
                theResult = 1;
                break;
            default:
                theResult = 0;
                printf("Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable: ");
                scanf("%c", &singleLetter);
                clearKeyboard();
            }
        } while (!theResult);

        return finalValue;

    }
```

And this is the code im not sure with NEAR THE END OF THE CODE:

```
void getName(struct Name *contactName) {

            printf("Please enter the contact's first name: ");
            scanf("%s", (*contactName).firstName);
            printf("Do you want to enter a middle intial(s)? (y or n): ");

            if (yes() == 1) {
                printf("Please enter the contact's middle intial(s): ");
                scanf("%s", (*contactName).middleInitial);

            }

            printf("Please enter the contact's last name: ");
            scanf("%s", (*contactName).lastName);
        }

        // getAddress:
        void getAddress(struct Address *

contactAddress) {


        printf("Please enter the contact's street number: ");

        (*contactAddress).streetNumber == getInt();

        printf("Please enter the contact's street name: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", (*contactAddress).street);

        printf("Do you want to enter an apartment number? (y or n): ");

        if (yes() == 1) {
            printf("Please enter the contact's apartment number: ");
            scanf("%d", (*contactAddress).apartmentNumber);
        }

        printf("Please enter the contact's postal code: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", (*contactAddress).postalCode);
        printf("Please enter the contact's city: ");
        scanf("%s", (*contactAddress).city);
    }

    // getNumbers:


    // getNumbers:
    // NOTE:  Also modify this function so the cell number is
    //        mandatory (don't ask to enter the cell number)
    void getNumbers(struct Numbers *contactNumber) {

        printf("Please enter the contact's cell phone number: ");
        scanf(" %s", (*contactNumber).cell);
        printf("Do you want to enter a home phone number? (y or n) ");

        if (yes() == 1) {
            printf("Please enter the contact's home phone number: ");
            scanf("%s", (*contactNumber).home);
        }

        printf("Do you want to enter a business number? (y or n) ");

        if (yes() == 1) {
            printf("Please enter the contact's business phone number: ");
            scanf("%s", (*contactNumber).business);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

AND BELOW THAT I HAVE THIS AND DONT KNOW WHAT TO DO. AS I STATED IN THE COMMENT:
```

> The purpose of this function is to set the values for a Contact using
>   the pointer parameter variable (set the Contact it points to).
>
> Use the pointer parameter received to this function to supply the appropriate
>   Contact member to the “get” functions (getName, getAddress, and getNumbers) to set the values for the Contact.

```
    void getContact(struct Contact *contact) {
        getName(contact);
        getAddress(contact);
        getNumbers(contact);
    }
```

THE BELLOW IS WHATS BEING ACCESSED/PRINTED. Whatever i enter, it doesnt show up because of void getContact(struct Contact *contact){ }

```
 getContact(&contact);
    printf("\nValues Entered:\n");
    printf("Name: %s %s %s\n", contact.name.firstName, contact.name.middleInitial, contact.name.lastName);
    printf("Address: %d|%s|%d|%s|%s\n", contact.address.streetNumber, contact.address.street, 
        contact.address.apartmentNumber, contact.address.postalCode, contact.address.city);
    printf("Numbers: %s|%s|%s\n", contact.numbers.cell, contact.numbers.home, contact.numbers.business);
```

Comment: Unrelated: `theResults = theResults++;` I'm not sure about C, but in C++ this would be undefined behavior.

Comment: @scohe001 It’s undefined in C, which is what’s relevant for this question, but since C++17 it’s well-defined (it sets `theResults` to the value of `theResults++`, so it undoes the side effect and puts it back where it was).

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` retains the newline `\n` in the buffer, the next time `scanf` is executed, the newline is read instead. Consider this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char x;
    scanf("%c", &x);

    printf("%d: '%c'\n", x, x);
    scanf("%c", &x);
    printf("%d: '%c'\n", x, x);

    return 0;
}
```

The output for the input `w<ENTER>s<ENTER>`

```
w
119: 'w'
10: '
'
```

In ASCII 119 is `'w'` and 10 is `'\n'`.

If you add a `getchar()` after the `scanf`, then `getchar()` reads the newline
and then nothing is in the buffer left, then the next `scanf` waits for the user input again:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char x;
    scanf("%c", &x);
    getchar();  // <-- look here

    printf("%d: '%c'\n", x, x);
    scanf("%c", &x);
    printf("%d: '%c'\n", x, x);

    return 0;
}
```

with the same input I get

```
w
119: 'w'
s
115: 's'
```

So, to solve your problem, you can add a `getchar()` after every `scanf`.

The best way to clear the buffer after using `scanf`:

```
int c;
while((c = getchar() !='\n') && c !=EOF );
```

---

**EDIT**

How to use `fgets`

> *man fgets*
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
> ```
>
> `fgets()` reads in at most one less than `size` characters from `stream` and stores them into the buffer
>   pointed to by `s`. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into
>   the buffer. A terminating null byte (`'\0'`) is  stored  after  the last character in the buffer.

Simply to get a line, you do:

```
char line[1024];
fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);
```

`fgets` will returns `NULL` when there is no more lines to read or there is an
error. Either way when that happens, you usually stop reading the file. That's
why to read all lines from a file (or multiple lines from the user), you do
this:

```
char line[1024];
while(fgets(lines, sizeof line, stdin))
{
    // do the work here
}
```

Bear in mind, that `sizeof line` in `fgets` is only correct, when `line` is an
array. If you for example allocate memory with `malloc`, you cannot use
`sizeof line`. If you get a pointer, then you have to know in advance how much
you can read.

```
size_t n = <some value>; // the value is not imporant,
                         // could be 100, could be 985
char *line = malloc(n);
if(line == NULL)
{
    // error handling, for example return error value
}

// only if line is not NULL
fgets(line, n, stdin);  // here I know the size in advance

// or as argument

void foo(char *buffer, size_t size)
{
    fgets(buffer, size, stdin);
    ...
}
```

If the length of the line is lesser than the size (minus 1) of the buffer, the
newline character will be stored in the buffer. If you don't need it, you can
set it to 0 in order to get rid of the newline:

```
char line[1024];
fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);

int len = strlen(line);
if(line[len - 1] == '\n')
    line[len - 1] = 0;
```

But if you don't mind having the newline, then you don't have to do that.

So you could write your `yes` function with `fgets`. Get the whole line, even
if you are only interested in the first character, you can ignore the rest of
the characters in the line.

```
#include <ctype.h>

int yes(void) {
    int theResults = 0;
    char line[1024];

    if(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not get line, aborting\n");
        return -1; // error value
    }

    while(toupper(line[0]) != 'Y' && toupper(line[0]) != 'N') {

        printf("*** INVALID ENTRY *** <Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable>: ");

        if(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "could not get line, aborting\n");
            return -1; // error value
        }
    }

    if(toupper(line[0]) == 'Y')
        theResults++;
    else
        theResults = 0;

    return theResults;
}
```

Comment: That fixed my main issue, but now when I purposely input a wrong letter , it makes me type the letter twice before i get the error message.

Comment: @Andrew that may be because of this `clearKeyboard` function. I don't know how it tries to do clear the buffer. I compiled your code and added the `getchar()` after the `scanf`s, and I don't have this behaviour.

Comment: i edited my original post with a new problem. Could you check it out

Comment: @Andrew you are calling `yes` twice in a row in `getName`. I advice you **not** to use `scanf` for user input. Use `fgets` instead (which read a whole line) and then check for contents of the line. The behaviour is much more predictable.

Comment: I have not really learned fgets so im not too sure about how to use it

Comment: yes i know i have to use fgets but the parameters are different. Do you know what i would have to write in order to get fgets to work? fgets (???);

Comment: there are a lot of things in that program you edited that I have not learned in class so I wouldn't be able to use that. It would be best if i could be just using scanf for now.

Comment: i have found  a solution to the problem to the problem. But i have a remainder of 2 problems. 1. is for the 'Y' and 'y'. If i were to type "yes" the program only takes the first letter so i end up getting the letter 'y' instead of "yes" so it passes it. 2. I have no idea what im suppose to do. Im given this statement "Use the pointer parameter received to this function to supply the appropriate Contact
member to the “get” functions (getName, getAddress, and getNumbers) to set the
values for the Contact. " I will update my original thing so you can see

Comment: @Andrew if you want to scan the word `"yes"`, then `char word[10];scanf("%s", word);getchar();` is the way to go. Note that word cannot be longer than 9 characters long.